# Summing values of grid moving upstream along flow paths in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, flow

I would like to sum the values of a grid, moving upstream along flow paths. In other words, I have a grid A with a value for each cell. I need to build a new grid, B, in which the value of each cell should be the sum of the A values of all the cells located downstream along the flow path.

How can this be done in GRASS?

Comment: what do you mean with flow path? the cell i = 1, j = 1 in grid B is the sum of all the cells in grid A?

Answer (score 1):

`r.watershed` allows you to specify the "flow" for each cell. So, `r.watershed elev=DEM flow=A accumulation=B` might work, but it isn't clear from your question if this is what you want. In this scenario, `B` is the accumulated value of all **upstream** cells. If this is not what you want, then `r.watershed` is probably still a good first step, and the output from that can be used with [r.stream.channel](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.stream.channel.html) or other [hydrology](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/keywords.html#hydrology) modules.

See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.watershed.html